# What type of query will accomplish this?

Tags: mysql

I want a query where searching for 'dave', will display the top three rows. 'mike' and 'carl' both have the parentid of dave.   So the three rows displayed will be the top three.

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id |  parentid|     user   |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |     null |     dave   |
|  2 |        1 |     mike   |
|  3 |        1 |     carl   |
|  4 |        2 |     rick   |
|  5 |        4 |     mike   |
```

What type of query will accomplish this?  A nested query?

Answer (score 2):

No nesting

```
select 
  c.*
from 
  YourTable c
  left join YourTable p on p.id = c.parentid
where
  p.user = 'dave' /* for the 'children' */ or 
  c.user = 'dave' /* for Dave himself */
```

If you don't want Dave himself be returned, but only the children, you can leave 'c.user' from the `where` clause. In this case you can also change `left join` to `inner join` which is merginally faster, although you may not notice it in this query.

Comment: thanks, so with inner joins you declare a table name, in this case you used 'c' and 'p'? Thanks this is great.

Comment: you give a table an alias. It makes your queries clearer and shorter. And it allows you to join a table to itself, as I've done here. Aliasing and joining are separate techniques, although often used together. The join is performed to join all records to their parents. That way, you can return all children by filtering for their parent's name. You could do this with a nested query, but that is likely to be slower, especially in MySQL (it hates nested queries).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from
table_name as partA inner join table_name as partB on partA.id = partB.parentid
Where partA.user = "Dave" or partB.user = "Dave"
```